# Proof Verification- proving that a sequence is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Prove that \begin{array}{l}\left\{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right\},\ n\in\mathbb{N}\\
\end{array} is a Cauchy sequence.
This is what I have so far:
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $m,n >k$.
Then,$$\begin{gather}\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k}\\
\therefore \frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{2}{2^k}\end{gather}$$
Then I was thinking of assuming $\frac{2}{2^k}<\epsilon$.
Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: Yes. You are nearly there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just observe that
$$\lim_n \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}= \lim_n (1-2^{-n}) = 1$$
and convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences?

Comment: He may not be allowed to use those things for the exercise. This approach will work though.